# Using tilde in script tag src attribute

Tags: asp.net, routes, tilde

In my asp.net website using `MasterPage` and `Routing` I use a tilde in the `href` attribute of the `link` tag for the stylesheet in the `head` section of the MasterPage. Like this:

```
<link href="~/Styles/Main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Which works like a charm. Since the website uses routing the url will contain more and more `/`, yet the stylesheet's href remains valid because the tilde points to the root of the web application and the styles are used.

I tried using the same technique for the `src` attribute of the `script` tags, but this doesn't seem to produce the expected result. I tried:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

But this just outputs the tilde character to the HTML of the page instead of replacing it with the root of the web application as it does for the `href` attribute. My experience is that asp.net replaces tilde in `href` attributes but not in `src` attributes.

How can I make the tilde work in the `src` atrribute of script tags?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure there is a way to get it to work correctly without a bit of assistance. This should work, not as nice as the `link` though:

```
<script src="<%=ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")%>"></script>
```

Comment: Haha +1 thanks for this suggestion. I think it might work but I'm inclined to mildly reject this on aesthetic grounds. I appreciate you answering my question but I was hoping for a more "elegant" solution. Asp.net already does the right behaviour for `href` attributes, I was hoping I could add `src` to a list somewhere to make it work.

Comment: Have you tried adding a runat="server" attribute to the script tag?

Comment: Then it attempts to execute javascript server side. Not a good plan.

Comment: Well, you should then add a type attribute so it knows its "text/javascript"

Comment: @armen.shimoon: ...and adding `type='text/javascript'` doesn't stop it running server-side, it tells it to run javascript server-side!

Comment: Isnt it `<script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js")%>"></script>`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, what you want just doesn't work (although I agree it should).

If you are using a script manager, then you can do something that is reasonably close:

```html
<asp:ScriptManager>
   <Scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Path="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" />
   </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I accepted the answer a little less than 10 years ago. By now the software that uses this solution is probably end-of-life. 

Comment: @Bazzz: I understand, I put the answer out there for others that are still dealing with this issue.